# Newton json version issue whie running webapi project

Tags: c#, json.net, nuget

I am getting this annoying error when running a webapi application. I am using newton JSON - version 9.01.

> {"Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"}

My project .netFramework is 4.0. To help solve this issue I had added a dependency assembly:

```xml
<assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json"
    publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.0.0.0" newVersion="9.0.0.0" />
```

and my project package.config

```xml
<package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.0.0" targetFramework="net40" />
```

Both are equal but I am still getting error. Why is this happening? This is strange because my error message shows different assembly version. I have already updated newtonjson 9.0.0 and am using it, but the error throws differently. 
I have tried installing newtonjson 6.0.0, and then the package manager console is throwing an error:

> Unable to find version '6.0.1' of package 'Newtonsoft.Json'.

Sometimes when downgrading to a lower version newton json, C# dependency is not supported already or installed like it shows.
What should I do? I am very new in installing nuget pakages .  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Try by clean and rebuild the solution

Answer (score 0):

in Package Manager Console:

Update in project: in pakage manager console close the targeting project and reinstall Newton soft and do a rebuild

```
Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json -Reinstall
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your solution have multiple projects that target different versions of Newtonsoft.Json?  Right-click the solution and Manage NuGet packages.  If Newtonsoft.Json shows up in the Consolidate tab, then update the projects to use the same version.